# Input tag not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a normal `input` tag in React on my page. The problem is everything renders correctly, but input tag always throws an error.

```
ReactDOM.render(<input type="text" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This statement is throwing error:

[image: React Error]

Every component, no matter how complex, is rendering correctly as long as it doesn't have an input tag. Note that when I tried to render a single input tag, it didn't work. I am using React CDN with babel.

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type="text/babel"` to script tag. ex:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
        <input type="text" />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: This is the full code. I can't render even a single input tag.

Comment: If you check me jsfiddle. It is working fine. Did you add `<div id='root'></div>` ?

Comment: I know it works fine, this is the first time it isn't. And if you look at the error, you will see it's not something you get normally. If you forget `text/babel`, you get `unexpected < symbol` and if you forget `div id="root"` you get nothing rendered.